# Find and Replace only the first instance of a word in a cell

Tags: excel

I have almost 2000 rows of content (all product descriptions for a website rebuild, no data) that I've edited and now need to include a Trademark symbol or Registered symbol on various product names and technologies throughout the worksheet. Using Find and Replace would be the fastest way to accomplish this, but the problem is, I only want the symbol to occur on the first instance of the word in the cell and not any following instances.

For example, if I Find and Replace "Nike shoes" with "Nike® shoes". The result would be:

> Nike® shoes are built to last for years. Every pair of Nike® shoes is covered by our full lifetime warranty.

But what I really want is the following:

> Nike® shoes are built to last for years. Every pair of Nike shoes is covered by our full lifetime warranty.

*Is there any way to create a function for finding and replacing the first instance of a word in a cell?*

Just a side note, I've never used excel before now so I'm new to this.

Comment: Study [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332).

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly you can try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(Cell of the text, "Old Text", "New text", 1).
```

`1` means that you want only one instance of the word to be replaced.

Example:
Let say the text is in cell A1

Nike shoes are built to last for years. Every pair of Nike shoes is covered by our full lifetime warranty.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "Nike", "Nike®", 1)
```

It worked well for me, for exactly the same problem.

Comment: .............................nice answer ! ...........................